# anaconda installation error and jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

When I install Anaconda, it does not start and gives an error.

And when I try to use Anaconda prompt to boot jupyter notebook, it gives this error and nothing opens at all.

this is the error:

```
(base) C:\Users\stockland>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\stockland\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 77, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\asynchronous\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\asynchronous\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.channels import HBChannel 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\channels.py", line 12, in <module>
    import zmq.asyncio 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    from zmq import backend 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    raise original_error from None 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first) 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 32, in select_backend
    mod = import_module(name) 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
  File "C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import)

(C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Comment: It looks like probably an issue with your environment.  Did you activate the anaconda environment?  It also looks like you have a standard Python 3.8 installation on your PYTHONPATH which is causing problems.

Comment: yes i have python 3.8 path in my computer

Comment: After activating the anaconda environment what does `echo %PYTHONPATH%` output?

Comment: Should I enter echo %PYTHONPATH% in the anaconda prompt?

Comment: C:\Users\stockland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages;C:\Users\stockland

Comment: thsi is the output

Comment: this post's "code" *was* horribly misformatted...

Answer (score 0):

Please do the following:

`pip uninstall pyzmq`

`pip install pyzmq`

The thing with conda is that it may have some conflicts. Using this simple method with pip command, should help you to remove those conflicts